# How to display server side validations for individual input fields when using AngularJS and Springboot?

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

so my question is if this is possible to display the errors on top of individual input fields when using AngularJS service to call Rest controller, because when response is received from AngularJS service, it comes as a single error message, so either that whole errors will be displayed on UI.

For example we are validating field A, B and C using server side validation, and there are 3 types of error messages coming from server but as a single string.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the return type of your method. If return type is string then it will return as single string. Please use class object concept or dynamic json object in var type variable or use pipe ("|") separator and split it to show on page.